# Are earlier statements executed in a method supposed to be slower?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, benchmarking

I was benchmarking the performance of streams that collect into an `ArrayList` of predefined capacity versus one with the default capacity.

First I add a number of random integers to a `master` list, then take the stream of that list and collect it into an `ArrayList`. The first stream collects into an `ArrayList` without a predefined capacity (so its initial capacity is 10). The other one does.

Code:

```
int capacity = 8000; 
var master = new ArrayList<Integer>(capacity); 
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    master.add(rnd.nextInt()); 
}
print("Adding elements to list with default capacity..."); 
var sw = Stopwatch.startNew();
List<Integer> defaultList = 
         master
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
sw.stop();
String elapsedDefault = sw.toString(); 
print("Adding elements to list with predefined capacity..."); 
sw.restart();
List<Integer> predefined = 
         master
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() 
                -> new ArrayList<>(master.size())));
sw.stop();
String elapsedPredefined = sw.toString(); 
System.out.println("Time taken with default size: " + elapsedDefault); 
System.out.println("Time taken with predefined size: " + elapsedPredefined);
```

This outputs:

```
Adding elements to list with default capacity...
Adding elements to list with predefined capacity...
Time taken with default size: 12.63ms
Time taken with predefined size: 3.66ms
```

However, if I *flip* the order of which stream comes first in the code, I get something like the below:

```
Adding elements to list with predefined capacity...
Adding elements to list with default capacity...
Time taken with predefined size: 13.17ms
Time taken with default size: 3.23ms
```

Does this have anything to do with compiler optimization or CPU operation? I can't think of another reason why this would happen. (Note: Insertion into predefined-capacity list only strictly gives better performance if the number of elements to add is VERY large, on the order of a few hundred million. Otherwise, it doesn't seem to matter outside of whether the statement comes first in the program.)

Comment: CPUs and OSes (lazy virtual memory allocation) have multiple warm-up effects. ([Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)) A JIT-optimizing JVM adds another layer of warm-up effects of its own.

Comment: Testing performance is tricky. [Benchmarking](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness) should be done with [jmh, the Java Microbenchmark Harness](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaMicrobenchmarking/article.html).